# Trouble creating a runnable JAR from Eclipse

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm trying to create a runnable JAR from https://bitbucket.org/madsen953/ethervisu in Eclipse. When I try to run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "Monitor" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnetpcap in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.jnetpcap.Pcap.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at ethervisu.monitors.JNetPcapMonitor.run(JNetPcapMonitor.java:28)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
    at processing.core.PFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadFont(Unknown Source)
    at jgv.graphics.JGVGraphics$GraphVisuApplet.setup(JGVGraphics.java:80)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load font /data/ArialMT-48.vlw. Make sure that the font has been copied to the data folder of your sketch.
    at processing.core.PApplet.die(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.die(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.loadFont(Unknown Source)
    at jgv.graphics.JGVGraphics$GraphVisuApplet.setup(JGVGraphics.java:80)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think this is because I'm unable to preserve the directory structure when creating the JAR. The font files are at the root instead of the `data` directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: That looks like another jar is missing, whatever holds jnetpcap.  Be sure to check the options so that it compiles and includes the necessary library in your jar so you don't have to install the jar in your path, nor include it as a separate file

Comment: I'm trying to get a handle on the font file first.

Comment: That error isn't a file i/o related error.  Your error is that it cannot find the class, which means you are missing a jar.  Afterwards you can use relative paths to avoid problems with your misplaced files.

Comment: I'm worried about `Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load font /data/ArialMT-48.vlw. Make sure that the font has been copied to the data folder of your sketch.`, which does seem to be an issue of finding the file.

Comment: try loading `./data/ArialMT-48.vlw` and put the data folder in the same directory as the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put the font files in a directory named `data` in the same directory as the jar and run it with `java  -Djava.library.path=jnetpcap-1.3.0 -jar thejar.jar` where `jnetpcap-1.3.0` is a directory where jnetpcap with its associated `.so` resides.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the path of JDK set properly pointing to correct library of java in buildpath.

and make sure correct jdk version is installed. no mess up with x86/x64 installs.`

Comment: I had to change the jpcap version to 64 bit, but that solved it. I'm trying to solve the font file issue now.